Modeling disease vs. microbiome: which should be the outcome?
I have a question related to microbiome research, an area where many researchers assess whether taxa abundances differ between disease and control groups. I often see statistical models where taxa serve as the outcome variable and disease status as the explanatory variable. However, I’m wondering if this model is more appropriate for evaluating whether the disease impacts the microbiome, rather than the reverse. Most researchers aim to find evidence that the microbiome impacts disease. Given that, would that model be inappropriate and would it be more appropriate to use a model where taxa serve as explanatory variables and disease status as the outcome? Perhaps the position in the equation, whether on the left or right side, is less important when using a linear model with only numerical variables and no covariates involved?


I’m wondering if this model is more appropriate for evaluating whether the disease impacts the microbiome, rather than the reverse. Most researchers aim to find evidence that the microbiome impacts disease.

The main problem is that the observational data typical of microbiome studies can't readily distinguish the causal direction of "impact." See "Causal Inference: What If?" for an introduction to the problems in making causal inference from observational data.
The most direct way to "find evidence that the microbiome impacts disease" is to do a controlled study in which the microbiome is altered and the effect on disease is observed. I can think of one such effort that led to a Nobel Prize for discovering that H. pylori infection can lead to gastritis, work that ultimately documented the role of that organism in development of peptic ulcers, but such experiments in humans are difficult even when they are ethically permissible.
For association studies one typically treats the variable that is least subject to error, or is given/controlled by the experimental design, as a "predictor" and the other as the outcome. For an association between disease and microbiome, on that basis it makes sense that "taxa serve as the outcome variable and disease status as the explanatory variable."

From my mentor Prof. John Petkau (Prof Emeritus in the Statistics department at University of British Columbia):
This comment implicitly assumes there is no conceptual difference between Y and X.  But, I feel that the roles of Y and X are distinguished by the question to be addressed.  Even in so-called "association studies", the underlying idea is (at least usually) prediction of Y from X ... which identifies what should be Y and what should be X.

From my mentor Prof. John Petkau (Prof Emeritus in the Statistics department at University of British Columbia):

You are absolutely correct that the most appropriate way to formulate
the model depends upon the question being asked.
If the question is the effect of disease status on taxa abundance(s),
then the abundance(s) should be used as response and disease status
should be used as predictor. If the question is the effect of taxa
abundance(s) on disease status, then disease status should be used as
the response and the abundance(s) should be used as predictors.
In my view, this is a fundamental principle so important even in the
linear model case ... as long as one is thinking of assessing effects.
Of course, if only interested in correlations, then no (linear) model
is required ... can simply evaluate the correlations of interest
directly.

